# Vue-way to change input type @focus?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

What is preferred Vue method of changing an input element's type onfocus? `i.e. onfocus="this.type = 'date'"`

Specifically, I want to toggle an input type from text to date take advantage of the placeholder property.

***Attempt:***

```
<template>
    <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Birthday"
        value="foo"
        @focus="setType('date')"
        @blur="setType('text')"
    />
</template>
<script>
    ...
    export default defineComponent({
        setup(){
            const el = ref<HTMLInputElement>()
            const setType = (x: string) => el.type = x

            return {el, setType}
        }
    })
</script>
```

***Error:***

```
Property 'type' does not exist on type 'Ref<HTMLInputElement | undefined>'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add another property called `elType` and bind it to the `type` attribute :

```
<template>
    <input
        :type="elType"
        placeholder="Birthday"
        value="foo"
        @focus="setType('date')"
        @blur="setType('text')"
    />
</template>
<script>
    ...
    export default defineComponent({
        setup(){
            const el = ref<HTMLInputElement>()
           const elType=ref('text')
            const setType = (x: string) => elType.value = x

            return {el, setType,elType}
        }
    })
</script>
```